# Javascript for loop is not waiting for function response

Tags: javascript

I am using loop and inside that I am calling a function but when I check console, for loop is not waiting for function respone, I mean loop are completed before function response. Here is the code:

```
 $scope.increment = 0;
 var count = 0;
 $scope.passingDistance = [];
 $scope.resultsDetails = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < $scope.latitude.length; i++) {
   console.log("i-:", i);
   var lati = $scope.latitude[i];

   for (var j = 0; j < $scope.longitude.length; j++) {
     console.log("j", $scope.increment);
     var longi = $scope.longitude[$scope.increment];
     $scope.getDistance(lati, longi);
     // here I want to wait for loop until
     // I am not getting this function return value...
     $scope.increment = $scope.increment + 1;
     break;
   }
 }
```

Comment: which function you are calling?

Comment: Are you calling an asynchronous function?

Comment: Yep, one must assume that `$scope.getDistance(lati, longi);` is asynchronous.

Comment: i am using distance matric (service.getDistanceMatrix) of google api i just want to return distance for all lati and lng..and i want to push the distance to array variable each time loop is running..

Comment: make `$scope.getDistance(lati, longi)`  return data into new var which you will use on lines below

Comment: > i am using distance matric...

Comment: > i am using distance matric...

Async code, [read about it](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-sync-async-javascript-node/).

Comment: Take a look at [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [some examples](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) and you will need to do something similar with your code.

Answer (score 0):

The Google API function `service.getDistanceMatrix` is asynchronous.

With such asynchronous functions you often find a last parameter called `callback`, because your code won't wait for the answer of this function.

[Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_requests) as you can see here there is a callback function in `service.getDistanceMatrix` as well. Now you'll have to include this callback in your wrapper function as well.

Using this you'll be able to modify your code like this

```
// lati, longi, callback (is just a function witch runs at the end)
$scope.getDistance(lati, longi, function(){
     `//here i want to wait for loop until i am not getting this function return value...`
});
```

Comment: lati ,longi is just a value that i am passing to that function and inside that function i am using distanceMatxic..

Comment: i just want to grab the returned value by index then increment loop ..so that i can push it to array..

Comment: Perhaps you can update your question tags to say that you are using the Google Maps API?

Comment: yes, you'll have to pass callback as well, you then pass it just straight again to `getDistanceMatrix `.

Comment: @AshishSinha you'll only get the returned value inside that function, since `getDistanceMatrix ` is a "non-blocking" request -> your code will just run and ignore the result of this function. That's why it needs a callback, it call the callback function when all the answers are there

Answer (score 0):

`service.getDistanceMatrix` is Asynchronous. Either you have to rewrite the code using `callback` properly or do this not-recommended lock:

```
$scope.lock = true;
$scope.getDistance(lati, longi, function(){
   $scope.lock = false; 
});
while($scope.lock){
    setTimeout(function(){
       ;
    }, 10);
}
```

Pass the lock function to `service.getDistanceMatrix`'s as callback

Edit: Clarification for using callback.
Rewrite `$scope.getDistance` like below:

```
$scope.getDistance = function(lati, longi, callback){
    // other code
    service.getDistanceMatrix({Your_parameters},callback);
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to pass lock function a callback ..Thank you